# Window.Ko is undefined

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I am trying to use the PrettyCheckable Plugin alongside with KO & requireJS.

Inside the PrettyCheckable Plugin, window.ko is undefined hence the checked event is not getting triggered

```
if (window.ko) {
   ko.utils.triggerEvent(input[0], 'click');
} 
else {
   input.click();
}
```

Require JS config

```
var require = {
    locale: 'en',
    baseUrl: '/Scripts',
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min",
        "knockout": "lib/vendor/knockout/knockout-2.3.0",
        "pretty-checkable": "Lib/Vendor/jQuery/Plugins/prettycheckable/prettycheckable"
    },
    shim: {

        "knockout": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: 'ko'
        },
        "pretty-checkable": {
            deps: ["jquery", "knockout"]
        },
    },
    waitSeconds: 0
};
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Formatting the config would make it easier for folks to read.

Comment: Where is the first code snippet actually used? And if you're using RequireJS, then you probably should be trying to avoid using globals (`window.ko`).

Answer (score 0):

You need the first code snippet to be run inside of a requirejs callback so that knockout is loaded as a dependency. You're using "window.ko" which only works if you're loading knockout without using require js.